# Continue to next step on click of Ship Here button

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, magento2checkout

I am working on a project where I have to customize the checkout process. So I need a functionality where I want to move to the next step on selection of the shipping address.

Below is my shipping-address page. And I want, when I click on "Use this address" button, it should select the address and take the customer to the next step. Basically onclick on "Use this address" button, it should do the functionality of next button.

[image]

Please let me know, if anyone done this before.

Comment: Could you give more detail or post an image illustrate your requirement?

Comment: @Jimmy, please find my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should do it. There are 2 reasons:

1. Shipping/Payment methods are depend on address.

So when you change the address, it will take sometimes to recalculate the rates and update the UI.

And then if shipping method change, users will have to manually select it again.

2. When users accidentally clicked the button.